# How to display articles from a specific category instead of all the articles

Tags: php

I'm working on a version of the [mediumish theme](https://github.com/bludit-themes/mediumish) for [bludit](https://github.com/bludit/bludit).

By default the theme displays on the homepage a list of all articles in the first section of the page. I would like to display instead the list of articles from one specific category.

I have tried to add an `if` condition matching the right category but I may be wrong.

Here is what I tried:

```php
<?php if ($WHERE_AM_I == 'home'): ?>

    <!-- Begin Featured
    ================================================== -->
    <section class="featured-posts">
    <div class="section-title">
        <h2><span>La structure</span></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card-columns listfeaturedtag">

        <?php if ($category->key() == 'structure'): ?>

        <?php 
            // Get the first and second page from the content
            $featured = array_slice($content, 0, 2);
            $content = array_slice($content, 2); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php
            foreach ($featured as $page):
        ?>
        <!-- begin post -->
                <!-- Here goes the code for each post -->
        <!-- end post -->
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End Featured
    ================================================== -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I expect it to display the articles from category called `structure` but I have nothing on the page.

[Here](https://docs.bludit.com/en/dev-snippets/categories) are some snippets about categories in bludit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found out how to do what I want :

```php
        <?php 
            $categoryKey = 'structure';
            $category = getCategory($categoryKey);

            $featured = array_slice($category->pages(), 0, 3);
            $content = array_slice($content, 1); ?>

        <?php
            foreach ($featured as $pageKey):
        ?>

        <?php $page = new Page($pageKey); ?>
```